# How to decrease time period of Workmanager in Android?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to sync the data between mobile to server and from server to mobile with less time.

I have checked about Workmanager, periodicTimeRequest time period is 15 mins.Can this be achieved in less time with alternative solution ?

How can i achieve this ?

Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to stick with `WorkManager` because with `WorkManager` you are assured that the job will be done within 15-ish minutes. While if you use alternative solution you'll have to make sure it is running, make sure it stops if the user close your app, handle errors and such.

PS: to answer the title, you can't decrease the time period of 15min of `WorkManager`